# $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$. Prove that if $z = a + bi$ is a zero of $f(x)$ then $z = a − bi$ is also a zero of $f(x)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, polynomials, ring-theory

Let $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$. Prove that if $z = a + bi$ is a zero of $f(x)$ then $z = a − bi$ is also a zero of $f(x)$.

I'm learning about polynomial rings but my book and my instructor never explain what a zero is in terms of polynomial rings...or what a polynomial ring is. Does this mean that $f(z) = 0?$ Does it mean that $z \in \mathbb{R}$? It would be also appreciated if someone could point me to a resource about polynomial rings that actually explains what they are.

Comment: Yes that means $f(z)=0$. Just treat a polynomial ring as a polynomial...

Comment: So then $f(a+bi) = 0$ but where do I go from there? I think I have that, $f(a+bi) = g_0 + g_1 (a+bi) +... + g_n (a+bi)^n= 0$. @KennyLau

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $x$ being a zero of $f$ just means that $f(x) = 0$.

As for what a polynomial ring $R[x]$ is, it's simply creating a ring (in the usual way) by taking a base ring $R$, and then using it to create polynomial in $x$ with coefficients from $R$.

So the elements of $R[x]$ are simply polynomials $f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{n} a_i .x^i$, where $n$ is some finite number (for $f$ to be a polynomial and not a series). Notice also that $i$ starts from $0$, so $g(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}$ is not a legal element of $R[x]$.

As for the actual question itself, that is a consequence of the fundamental theorem of Algebra, and I can't quickly think of a ring theoretic way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Use that for the complex conjugate we have

$$(1)\;\overline{z+w}=\overline z+\overline w\;,\;\;(2)
;\overline{wz}=\overline w\overline z\,,\;\;(3)\;\;\overline z=z\iff z\in\Bbb R$$

So that

$$p(\overline z)=\overline{p(z)}=\overline0=0$$